# it's possible to obtain the data stored in a label label to assign it to another variable and thus be able to graph it?

Tags: javascript, html, graphics, tags, label

my label

Porcentaje:

here I am adding the result of my operation to the label
document.getElementById("percentage1").innerHTML = perc1 + "%";

I am trying to assign it to another variable the value of the label
let PorcElement6 = document.getElementById("percentage1").label;

I am trying to add that variable to the graph
data: [PorcElement6, PorcElement7, PorcElement8, PorcElement9, PorcElement10],

Comment: Don't add unrelated (`graphics`, `tags`) tags to your question. Have a look at [How do I format my posts using Markdown or HTML?](https://stackoverflow.com/help/formatting), [What topics can I ask?](https://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic), [How do I ask a good question?](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) and [How much research effort is expected of Stack Overflow users?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/261592/how-much-research-effort-is-expected-of-stack-overflow-users)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Read it with `.innerText`,  for example:

```html
<label id="percentage1">44.3%</label>
```

```js
const labelElement = document.getElementById("percentage1");

const text  = labelElement.innerText; // "44.3%"
const int   = parseInt(labelElement.innerText, 10); // 44
const float = parseFloat(labelElement.innerText); // 44.3
```

Comment: What is your answer doing? And why? Why `.innerText` when OP is using `.innerHTML`? Why do you assume that `labelValue` should be a number? Which is already available in `perc1`? And how can you answer that question at all without the relevant markup, an actual description of what should happen and when?

Comment: @Andreas the OP is using `.innerHTML` for writing the value, while I'm using `.innerText` to read it. I think it should be a number because the OP wants to plot it in a graph.

Comment: _"while I'm using .innerText to read it."_ - That doesn't answer the "Why" question. _"OP wants to plot it in a graph"_ - Maybe, but we don't know for sure.